# Spring Data JPA Repository wiring for integration test not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, integration

I'm trying to write an integration test for my TemplateRepository using an inmemory db(HSQL).

```
public interface TemplateRepository extends CrudRepository<TemplateEntity, String> {

    TemplateEntity findByIdAndTemplateName(String id, String templateName);

    void deleteByIdAndTemplateName(String cifId, String templateName);

}
```

This is the test class so far:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration  
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class TemplatesRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TemplateRepository templateRepository;

    private EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("sql/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("sql/insert-data.sql")
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {   }
}
```

Which is using this context config:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("sql/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("sql/insert-data.sql")
            .build();
        return db;
    }
}
```

And the application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the declared dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The autowiring of the repository to the test class is not working. I'm getting the following error:

```
11:25:57.300 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@5f3a4b84] to prepare test instance [TemplatesRepositoryTest@4eb7f003]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TemplatesRepositoryTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private TemplateRepository TemplatesRepositoryTest.templateRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [TemplateRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have tried the solutions in all the related topics found, but none seems to fix the problem. Could someone point out what I'm missing here?

I'm using SpringBoot 1.3.1.RELEASE and SpringDataJpa 1.9.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Try adding @ComponentScan to your Application class so that Spring finds the TemplateRepository bean. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Comment: I don't see an `@EnableJpaRepositories` anywhere.

Comment: How is your structure of your project? Maybe the repository interface is not in the same package like your SpringBootApplication?

Comment: @Alan Hay I have tried that and nothing changed

Comment: Add @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={""}) to your config classes

Comment: @chrylis If I add EnableJpaRepositories annotation on the test configuration class I receive: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

Comment: @Semaphor The project only has 1 package.

Comment: @AlanHay If I add EnableJpaRepositories annotation on the test configuration class I receive: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

Comment: Where is your EntityManagerFactory defined? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736241/spring-missing-jpa-metamodel

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting the same issue and found that when using autoconfiguration for **CrudRepository**, **PagingAndSortingRepository** and **JpaRepository** one *should not* call initialization scripts within **DataSource** bean as the content of the in-memory database as H2 is overwritten by the **DatabasePopulator** bean. Try the configuration code as below:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;

@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabasePopulator databasePopulator(DataSource dataSource) {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.setContinueOnError(true);
        populator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);
        populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("sql/create-db.sql"));
        populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("sql/insert-data.sql"));
        try {
            populator.populate(dataSource.getConnection());
        } catch (SQLException ignored) {
        }
        return populator;
    }
}
```

In case of "solid" database, as for example MySQL, one may explicitly provide NULL value:

```
@Bean
public DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    return null;
}
```

Hope it solves your problem