# How to enable Spring Data JPA within a Spring XD module? (JPA metamodel must be present!)

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-xd

Has anyone been able to successfully use Spring Data JPA within a Spring XD 1.3.1 module?

I'm currently running into issues as soon as I add the Spring Data JPA jars to the Spring XD lib folder:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.admin.AdminServerApplication.run(AdminServerApplication.java:100) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.admin.AdminServerApplication.main(AdminServerApplication.java:82) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:276) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:52) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:71) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you initialised a JPA `EntityManagerFactory`? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736241/spring-missing-jpa-metamodel) may help.

Comment: Yes, I had but it crashes even before starting initializing my custom module.